# I am looking for lyrics of the song: Thomas Bergersen - A Place in Heaven

Tags: lyrics, classical-music, language

It has two versions, one is sung by Jenifer Thigpen as voice over. I am looking for lyrics of the version with her voice.

I found lyrics in [this website](https://flowlez.com/en/songs/a-place-in-heaven-1759313/) but it is in English and it does not sound like what I hear in the song.

Comment: The lyrics you found seem to be a translation. Most lyrics-gatherers seem to conclude it's an instrumental track. It is possible the exact lyrics have never been published.